# class A extends B implements C

Tags: java, interface

Question: Reference of Test16 is placed in variable m1 of type My3 (Line A) and function show() in Test17 class has no relation with function show() in interface My3;
    Then how it's possible that show() function in class Test17 is executed by m1.
   The code is as follows:

```
    class Test17{
        public void show(){
            System.out.println("Show1");
        }
    }
    class Test16 extends Test17 implements My3 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            My3 m1=new Test16();//<----Line A
            m1.show();
        }
    }
    interface My3{
        public abstract void show();
    }
```

The output of following code is:Show1

Comment: In order for `Test16` to implement `My3`, it must provide a method `public void show()`. And it does, because such a method is defined in its superclass. So `Test17.show` provides the implementation of `My3.show` in the class `Test16`.

Comment: Note in particular that although, yes, the object referenced by variable `m1` is a `Test17`, it is more specifically a `Test16`.  That is what connects `Test17.show()` with `My3.show()`.

Comment: Thanks guys..I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter that Test17 implements My3, the method signature is the same, so it works! The method is inherited to its child, which implements the interface.

- My3 is an interface, which defines show().
- m1's implementation is Test16.
- Test16 inherits Test17 (and it's method)

When show is called, the only implementation of show() is found in Test16's parent: Test17.

Answer (score 0):

Since class Test16 extends the Class Test17 , So now the Class Test16 IS-A a Test17 means class Test16 is child of Class Test17, its inherit all the properties and behavior of Test17. Now Test16 have a method

```
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Show1");
    }
```

Now, when you implements the interface My3, and its also have a method of same signature, which is in Class Test17( with body ) ,  now this method is in class Test16 due to extends.

So by default you providing the implementation of interface method by Class Test17 in Class Test16 by extending the Class Test17. Because both interface method and Class Test17 method have same signature